# Nodejs Access Firebase Database node ids

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a basic Nodejs server connected to my ios App and firebase client. I want to fetch data from the database, which is in and system generated alphanumeric format(ex: -ibdUKV6168ded). I obviously cannot input that manually every time theres such entry, also I dont want to fetch it by having an index number of the array. How can I fetch that key.

Plus, Every time such key is generated, i want to read the document present in it.

I am out of ideas.

Any help will be much appreciated.

The database looks like this: [image]

I want to fetch the post keys explicitly. I have a on() event called each time a new post is generated. How can I reference them.

Comment: You'll need to figure out a way to construct a query the identifies the data you want, or store that push id elsewhere so it can be found and referenced in a query.  This all depends on what data you're actually storing.  Without that information, there's nothing we can recommend.

Comment: I have social app, where each post is a new entry. Each of the posts contain the author and caption and each of them has a unique id. Now I want to fetch this id. And there are several of them in my document. And how to fetch those id's is what I have issue with. Hope i am clear.

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot or diagram of your data along with a description in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look. Let me know if more info is required. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a way to uniquely identifying the post, other than the generated push id.  If the push id isn't going to work for you, you'll need to some up with some other way of identifying the post you're looking for.

Comment: In such case what do you suggest. How can I make this push id unique and identifiable at the same time. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by the firebase functions. Although, they are in beta, they are a great help. Functions along with Admin SDK provide really great combination to deal with such querying of data, where the values are uniquely identified.